# Confusing Java extend

Tags: java, extends

I am trying to understand the usage of Java extend.... I created a sample testing code to under how it works....

```
public class Parent {

    public String Msg="Original";

    public String getMsg() {
        return Msg;
    }
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        Msg = msg;
    }

    public void printing(){
        System.out.println(Msg);    
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    public HashMap<String, String> Msg2;

    public Integer Msg3;

    public HashMap<String, String> getMsg2() {
        return Msg2;
    }
    public void setMsg2(HashMap<String, String> msg2) {
        Msg2 = msg2;
    }

    public void printing(){
        System.out.println("1 : " + Msg);
        System.out.println( Msg2 );
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Child a = new Child();

        System.out.println(a.Msg.getClass());  // able to detect variable from parent

        System.out.println(a.Msg2.getClass()); // Not able to detected, even variable from                  
                               // same instance object child    
        System.out.println(a.Msg3.getClass()); // Not able to detected, even variable from                  
                               // same instance object child


        a.printing();

    }

}
```

I getting confuse why Msg variable from parent object can detected easy.

While Msg2 and Msg 3 coming from the same instance Child -> a can't recognize it's own variable.

The error message getting from Msg2 or Msg 3 is, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Is there anyone able to explain why java behave in such way ?

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized `Msg2` and `Msg3`. You need to use the `new` keyword to initialize them, so that they are not null.

add these two statements.

```
Msg2 = new HashMap<String,String>();

Msg3 = new Integer();
```

Comment: Thanks, If my understanding is correct... declaration,
    public HashMap<String, String> Msg2;
    public Integer Msg3;

Doesn't phyically create the object in runtime, which enable the getClass method to detect the object type...

Only after assignment then the object is created.... Am I right ?

Comment: Yeah, those two lines are just the declarations. They just create the references and those references are `null` until they are initialized with a `new` keyword, or by assigning a value to them in the case of the `Integer`. Declarations don't create the object, merely the reference that points to an object.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Msg` has been initialised to a non-null value (the string "Original") but the other fields have not, so they're null and you get an exception trying to call a method (`getClass`) on a null reference. If you just tried to print out `Msg2` rather than `Msg2.getClass()` then you'd see the value `null` with no exception.

Answer (score 0):

first set a value to your msg in your child class so its not null by default.

```
 Int Msg3 = 5;
```

and display it this way

```
System.out.println("Here is a msg:" + child.Msg4);
```